# Math font graphics: not so clear with libertinust1math

Tags: math-mode, graphics, math-fonts, libertinus

I'm writing a document with `\libertinus` font. In order to make the whole document graphically coherent, I'm also using `\libertinust1math` to write some mathematical formulae.
I like the general style, but I'm having a little trouble when I have to typesetting some mathematical expression.
Here a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %This pack allows to use UTF8 codification for special characters.
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %font enconding
\usepackage{comment} %This pack allows for multiple-lines comments.
\usepackage{enumitem} %This pack allows the creation of lists
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry} %This pack allows to set margins, paper size and so on.
\usepackage{mathtools} %This pack introduces several powerful math commands that are not provided by basic LaTeX. Mathtools includes amsmath package.
\usepackage{fancyhdr} %It allows some text formatting like chapter on top of each page.
\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\usepackage{array} %It allows tables formatting.
\usepackage{booktabs} %It allows to control the thickness of horizontal rules by toprule, midrule, bottomrule.
\usepackage{graphicx}


\usepackage{libertinus} %font
\usepackage{libertinust1math} %mathfont
\usepackage{microtype} %improves general typographic

\begin{document}

The generic $j$-th sub-interval starts at $t_\mathrm{(j-1)_+}$ and ends at $t_\mathrm{j_-}$

\end{document}
```

As you can see, I obtain an expression that is not so clear as it should be.

[image]

In particular the "t" with subscript doesn't look good, it appears like too close to both "bracket" and "j".
Is there a way to make it appear better? Am I using a wrong command?
I would like to keep using `\libertinust1math`(to preserve a certain graphic consistency), anyway if you know other better math-font options that could fit good with libertinus font, I would be happy to consider them.

Thank you!

Comment: I would start applying the `\mathrm` only to symbols, to keep math spacing: `$t_{{(\mathrm{j}-1)}_+}$` and maybe adding a bit of space after the `(`

Answer (score 2):

I would use the `\mathrm` only around the symbol (and not rely on it grouping things), and write:

```
The generic $j$-th sub-interval starts at $t_{{(\mkern1mu\mathrm{j}-1)}_+}$ and ends at $t_{\mathrm{j}_-}$
```

[image]

I did add a bit of space after the opening paren in the subscript to avoid clashing with the long `j` tail. I still feel that the `-` in the first subscript is too tight, I do not know why...

With standard (cm) fonts it is:

[image]

Comment: Inspired by your suggestion @Rmano, I've solved momentarily with this: `$t_{{\mkern2mu(\mkern1mu\mathrm{j}-1)}_+}$`. In this way I'm able to better control the spacing between "t" and the subscript. It seems to look better.

Answer (score 0):

In my pdf the distances are exactly the same with both -, measured from the outline of the j. cm font is slimmer than rm, and maybe because of this its natural spacing looks more spacious. The - in j-1 is centered well, though it does not look so due to the different forms of a j and a 1. Of course you could add \kern0.5pt before the first -, but adjusting all spaces manually, really is quite labourious.

```
 The generic $j$-th sub-interval starts at
 $t_{{(\kern0.5pt\mathrm{j}\kern0.5pt-1)_+}}$
 and ends at $t_\mathrm{j_-}$
```

(I prefer kerning by points, but anything could be used here.)